# MySQL - How to get the next row

Tags: mysql

So I have a student_profiles table and ranks table, I want to get the next rank based on the student rank. For example, I have rank 5 then the next rank will be rank 6. So this is my rank structure.

**RANKS TABLE:** 
`SELECT * FROM RANKS WHERE style_id = 1"`

```
id style_id level name   type   primary_colour secondary_colour
 1        1     1 Newbie double #4e90b2        #3aad04
22        1     2 Normal solid  #fba729        NULL
31        1     3 Expert solid  #4e805b        NULL
```

and this is **STUDENT_PROFILES TABLE**

```
  id   |    student_id  | rank_id
------------------------------------
    1  |        1       |   36  
    2  |        4       |   22  
    3  |        7       |   10
```

so all I have a variable is `student_id`, `rank_id` & `style_id`

so for example, I have this value `student_id = 4`, `rank_id = 22` & `style_id = 1`

It should return

```
id   style_id   level   name     type    primary_colour   secondary_colour
31 |        1 |     3 | Expert | Solid | #4e805b        | NULL
```

Comment: imo, The only time the concept of 'next row' applies is when you have an 'ordered list'? So, sort by rank and then process as required?

Comment: @RyanVincent No opinion needed, I think we absolutely need an ordering here to give meaning to "next."

Comment: Yeah I already sorted by `ranks.level`

Comment: why is it return a result like that, any details?

Comment: tried "select * from table where id = (select min(id) from table where id > yourid)"? For next record.

Comment: @reds cause I have a PHP that will just click button on `promote` on student. But having trouble on SQL

Answer (score 1):

Try with that:

```
SELECT * FROM `ranks` WHERE `level` > (SELECT `level` FROM `ranks` WHERE `id` = rank_id) LIMIT 1
```

But I think it isn't very effective solution.

Comment: what if I deleted the `level 3` and this will be the left `level 1, 2, 4`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the second row:
Do it like this:

```
select * from
(select * from table order by id asc limit 2) as a order by id desc limit 1
```

Any query structure it will work as you need second row if you follow that script.

Comment: This one will show second record always as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

One option for getting the next highest level in the `RANKS` table is to self-join this table on the `level` column, order ascending, and retain the very first record only.

```
SELECT r2.*
FROM RANKS r1
INNER JOIN
STUDENT_PROFILES s1
    ON r1.id = s1.rank_id
INNER JOIN
RANKS r2
    ON r2.level > r1.level
ORDER BY r2.level
LIMIT 1
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Note: If `RANKS` has duplicate levels, and you want the next level with regard to cardinality (i.e. you don't want a duplicate equal level returned), then my query could be slightly modified to filter out such duplicates.